# Should i change anything in this db design?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, database-design

As a uni project I am building a minimalistic jira like project management tool for agile projects. I will be using MySql with Java and Hibernate. So far this is my database schema.
Would you recomend any changes?

[image: The design]

Answer (score 2):

You have given us very little information about your requirements but I'll try to make some suggestions based on my (very limited) experience.

- You need to logically think about how you are going to use your database and create your design from that. In my opinion, a Project is the centre of the system, so everything should be thought of around entity.

  - A Project has many Sprints.
  - A Sprint has many Stories.
  - A Story has many StoryTasks.
  - Each StoryTask has an assigned user.
- So taking from this concept, we already have a simple design:

  ```
  Project --< Sprint --< Story --< StoryTask -- Person
  ```
- Then you can go into more detail, thinking of things like "Do I want my user to be able to work on more than one task?" If the answer is yes, then you can have a one to many relationship from Person:

  ```
  Project --< Sprint --< Story --< StoryTask >-- Person
  ```
- Not that you have your basic design that you  think would work, you can think in more detail about your queries. For example, if you want to get a list of all the people working on your project, you would have to write a long query which joins and searchers all of the tables involved. For a commonly  used functionality such as listing all people on a project, you can create a join between Person and Project:

  ```
  Person* >-- Project --< Sprint --< Story --< StoryTask >-- Person*
  ```
- Also, if you are planning on a person to be associated with more than one project and be able to query which projects a person has been part of you would need to create a relationship table

  ```
  Person* --< ProjectPersonnel >-- Project --< Sprint --< Story --< StoryTask >-- Person*
  ```

  It is always better to think of the queries you will be running before designing your database. For example, if you wanted a list of all the Projects a Person has been on, you could have a relatively  simple query

  ```
  SELECT
  proj.ProjectName
  FROM
  Person per
  LEFT JOIN ProjectPersonnel pp
  ON per.PersonId = pp.PersonId
  LEFT JOIN Project proj
  ON pp.ProjectId = proj.ProjectId
  WHERE
  per.FistName = 'Bob'
  ```

If you wanted a list of all the Stories associated to a Sprint in a Project, you have the structure in place to create a simple query for that

```
    SELECT
    story.StoryName
    FROM
    Story story
    LEFT JOIN Sprint sprint
    ON story.SprintId = sprint.SprintId
    LEFT JOIN Project proj
    ON sprint.ProjectId = proj.ProjectId
    WHERE
    proj.Name = "MyProject1"
    AND
    sprint.Number = "3"
```

As I say, I haven't got much experience in the field so there are definitely better suggestions out there - I just hope that this is somewhat useful.

Comment: And don't forget to consider what you will need for data reporting and not just data entry. It makes a big difference in the design of a database.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to locating `id` field to the first position, every table should has primary key, and every primary key should has different name with each other.

Like: `project` => `project_id` , `person` => `person_id`, .......

This action would facilitate you for database query and application that you deploy.
Hope this helps.

Comment: besides renaming this is there anything else?

Comment: Yes. As far I know(course in college (db design)) you must add prefix to every your field name. For example in table `project`, fields become : `project_id`, `project_name`, `project_description` OR with a bit prefix : `pro_id`, `pro_name`, `pro_description`